# Google plus trigger button file input

Tags: javascript, html

Does any know how Google plus trigger a button to then open a file input field?

Could they be using an iframe for legacy browsers, or is it a HTML 5 thing???

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am needing to make firefox 3.6 trigger an input file via a button.  I have read around not possible, but some how google plus can do it.

Comment: any one have an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I can only test with current firefox and chrom version. If it works in IE, you need at least IE 9 (I can't test in IE9).

HTML:

```
<div class="button_wrapper">
    <div class="button_visible" role="button">button description</div>
    <div class="button_invisible">
        <input type="file" class="button_input" tabindex="-1" multiple="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button_wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.button_visible {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 6px 6px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.button_invisible {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.button_input {
    position: absolute; 
    top: -10px;
    left: -445px; 
    opacity: 0; 
    font: 40px arial,sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Because I didn't want to set the width and height in all css classes, I added this JS:

```
$('.button_invisible').each(function() {
    $(this).width($(this).parent().width());
    $(this).height($(this).parent().height());
});
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmdag/).

Comment: firefox 3.6 works, thanks for that.  Hopefully now i can adapt that into this plugin - http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Comment: If you think this is the right answer, it would be nice to mark this as the right answer. This will raise your acception rate and more people will answer in the future.